# Issue with path containing [ and ( when using -Path

Tags: powershell, path

I try to write a script with PowerShell to move 3 folders. I've got some issue due to the different `[]` and `()` in my path. I can't change the path and want to find a solution.

The goal is to check where the 3 folders are and to change their position.

Here's my code:

```bsh
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

if(((Test-Path "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods\[TMX] IF2 Red Shed") -eq $True ) -and ((Test-Path "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods\[CP] Immersive Farm 2") -eq $True ) -and ((Test-Path "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods\[FTM] Immersive Farm 2 Forage+Ore") -eq $True ))
    {
    Move-Item -Path D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods\[TMX] IF2 Red Shed -Destination D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement
    Move-Item -Path D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods\[CP] Immersive Farm 2 -Destination D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement
    Move-Item -Path D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods\[FTM] Immersive Farm 2 Forage+Ore -Destination D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement
    }
Elseif(((Test-Path "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement\[TMX] IF2 Red Shed") -eq $True ) -and ((Test-Path "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement\[CP] Immersive Farm 2") -eq $True ) -and ((Test-Path "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement\[FTM] Immersive Farm 2 Forage+Ore") -eq $True ))
    {
    Move-Item -Path D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement\[TMX] IF2 Red Shed -Destination D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods
    Move-Item -Path D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement\[CP] Immersive Farm 2 -Destination D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods
    Move-Item -Path D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Map immersive\dossier de changement\[FTM] Immersive Farm 2 Forage+Ore -Destination D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods
    }
Else
    {
    $oReturn=[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("No folders")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `-LiteralPath` instead

When you use `-Path` with the Item/ChildItem provider cmdlets, PowerShell treats the argument as a potential wildcard pattern!

Since `[A-Z]` is a wildcard pattern construct, the file system globber won't actually resolve file(s) with a literal `[` or `]` in the name.

Using `-LiteralPath` will supress any attempt to expand wildcards:

```
Test-Path -LiteralPath "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Mods\[TMX] IF2 Red Shed"
```

Remember to quote paths with spaces as well!

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\path with [wildcards]\in\the\name.ext' -Destination 'C:\Destination\path\'
```

Comment: Your soution seems to work verry well with the Move-Item

But i still have some issue with the "Test-Path"

Comment: It's the parameter name (not the command noun), updated the answer

Comment: Great, you're welcome! When allowed to (there might be a time limit), please consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark on the left of it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found through tab completion that you can escape the square brackets with backquotes:

```
test-path '.\a`[hi`]\'
move-item '.\a`[hi`]\' foo
set-location '.\a`[hi`]\'
```